# What camera is used by Gazebo PR2?

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting the Manipulation Pipeline](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Starting%20the%20Manipulation%20Pipeline)

It says

```
  NOTE FOR ELECTRIC USERS: if you are using the narrow stereo cameras for stereo, you must launch as follows:
```

Is Gazebo PR2 use narrow stereo cameras?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36960/what-camera-is-used-by-gazebo-pr2?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several camera on the PR2 (on head and arms). You can check which there : [PR2 Specs - Willow Garage](http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/pr2/specs).

Which camera is used depends on the topic the node subscribe. Have a look to the launch file of the node you want to run for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0